# How to populate multiselect with selected values in php?

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery-chosen

I'm using codeigniter for development. I need to populate a multiselect with selected values

This is my json array (which i need to be selected):

```
["1","2","3","4"]
```

And this is my php code:

```
function tag($selected=0){
    $query = $this->db->get('tags');
    $html='';
    foreach($query->result() as $row){

        $html .='<option value="'.$row->id.'">'.$row->tag.'</option>';


    }
    return $html;
}
```

The **$selected** holds a json array. Now I need to populate compete tag list and selected items in json array.

How can i do it?
Can anyone tell me what method i use here?

Comment: How your json array looks like?

Comment: I'm saving json array like ["1","2","3","4"] which is id of the tag

Comment: And how do you exactly want to use that array? I didn't get that.

Comment: My table name is video and users can add tags for each video. tags are added by administrator, now i'm saving tags id as json array. when a user edit his video tag i need to show currently selected tag and available tags inside  multiselect i'm using chosen which is a javascript plugin for ui multiselect http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function tag($selected = null){
    $selected = ($selected === null) ? array() : json_decode($selected, true);
    $query = $this->db->get('tags');
    $html='';
    foreach($query->result() as $row){
        $isSelected = (in_array($row->id, $selected)) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
        $html .='<option value="'.$row->id.'"'.$isSelected.'>'.$row->tag.'</option>';


    }
    return $html;
}
```

Comment: I checked your answer bu getting error like         A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning
Message:  in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given
Filename: models/common.php
Line Number: 92

Comment: Also i can see the array is printing like Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I used same variable two times. Edited the answer

Comment: Yes i found it and fixed :)